# Django pass value from view to non-model form using kwargs

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, initialization

When I call my form within my view, I am trying to pass OTHER_VALUE to the form as an argument.

I am doing this because I want to get my validation out of my views and into my forms.

**views.py**

```
OTHER_VALUE = "the query that i run to get silly conditions"
if request.method=='POST':
  form = MY_FORM(request.POST, OTHER_VALUE)
```

**forms.py**

```
class MY_FORM(forms.Form):

  real_value = forms.CharField()
  def clean_real_value(self):
    if OTHER_VALUE ...
```

This expectedly throws the **error**:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'OTHER_VALUE'
```

=========

I've tried setting the init with a few different variations of `__init__`:

```
class MY_FORM(forms.Form):
  real_value = forms.CharField()

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    OTHER_VALUE = kwargs.pop('OTHER_VALUE') 
    super(MY_FORM, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['OTHER_VALUE'].initial = OTHER_VALUE
```

But I keep getting this type of **error**:

```
Exception Value: 'employee'
Exception Location: /Users/macbook/Desktop/OrgDB/orgchart/forms.py in __init__, line 42
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When passing the OTHER_VALUE to the form assign it a key `OTHER_VALUE=OTHER_VALUE` rather than just accessing it by position.

**views.py**

```
if request.method=='POST':
  form = MY_FORM(request.POST, OTHER_VALUE=OTHER_VALUE)
```

**forms.py**

```
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    self.OTHER_VALUE = kwargs.pop('OTHER_VALUE', None)
    super(MY_FORM, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

refer to OTHER_VALUE in the rest of the form class as `self.OTHER_VALUE`

Comment: @DhavalSavalia whoops. sorry about that. edits to the answer should fix.

Answer (score 2):

An approach is to have a Hidden Input as a field into your form

```
class MY_FORM(forms.Form):
    real_value = forms.CharField()
    other_value = forms.CharField(max_length=255,required=False,
                    widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

This new field can be served in your form, but the most important is to make sure that you add the value before you check the form validations.

```
OTHER_VALUE = "other_value"
if request.method=='POST':
    data = request.POST.copy()
    data['other_value'] = OTHER_VALUE
    form = MY_FORM(data)
    if form.is_valid():
         pass
```

In your form, you can have access to the value:

```
....# codes
    real_value = forms.CharField()
    other_value = forms.CharField(max_length=255,required=False,
                    widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    def clean_real_value(self):
        cleaned_data = super(FormName,self).clean_real_value()
        OTHER_VALUE = cleaned_data.get("other_value")
        if OTHER_VALUE ...
```

Comment: Upvoted! While i have no doubt that this would work, have used it before, and am grateful for the solution, I may not be so lucky as to have the data readily available to be passed as a hidden field. I'm troubleshooting the kwargs so that I can use the view as a data layer to retrieve whatever data/ queries I need on demand.